# Jekyll says Liquid Exception: invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII in documentation.html

Tags: utf-8, jekyll

I'm trying to run `jekyll build` on GitLab CI.

This is my `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
pages:
  script:
  - export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
  - export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
  - gem install jekyll
  - jekyll build --destination public
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - public
```

When the task runs I get this error:

```
      Generating... 
  Liquid Exception: invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII in documentation.html
jekyll 3.1.2 | Error:  invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII

ERROR: Build failed with: exit code 1
```

---

### More informations

`documentation.html` is:

```
---
layout: page
title: Documentation
description: Learn how to create awesome poppers
---
<!-- This page is generated by the grunt doc task of the master branch! Don't edit it! -->
{% markdown documentation.md %}
```

And `documentation.md` is a markdown document generated by `grunt-jsdoc2md`.

This is the `markdown` plugin I'm using:

```
=begin
  Jekyll tag to include Markdown text from _includes directory preprocessing with Liquid.
  Usage:
    {% markdown <filename> %}
  Dependency:
    - kramdown
=end
module Jekyll
  class MarkdownTag < Liquid::Tag
    def initialize(tag_name, text, tokens)
      super
      @text = text.strip
    end
    require "kramdown"
    def render(context)
      tmpl = File.read File.join Dir.pwd, "_includes", @text
      site = context.registers[:site]
      tmpl = (Liquid::Template.parse tmpl).render site.site_payload
      html = Kramdown::Document.new(tmpl).to_html
    end
  end
end
Liquid::Template.register_tag('markdown', Jekyll::MarkdownTag)
```

---

### Attempts

As you see, I've already tried setting `LC_ALL` and `LANG` to `en_US.UTF-8`.

I've also added `encoding: utf-8` to my `_config.yml` but it still doesn't work...

Another attempt was to use `@text = text.encode("iso-8859-1").force_encoding("utf-8").strip` in the markdown plugin.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I deleted the markdown plugin and used this:

```
---
layout: page
title: Documentation
description: Learn how to create awesome poppers
---
<!-- This page is generated by the grunt doc task of the master branch! Don't edit it! -->
{% capture documentation %}
{% include documentation.md %}
{% endcapture %}
{{ documentation | markdownify }}
```

Everything seems working fine now.

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem and found this solution, which worked for me. 
https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/14983

```
image: ruby:2.3

before_script:
  - apt-get update >/dev/null
  - apt-get install -y locales >/dev/null
  - echo "en_US UTF-8" > /etc/locale.gen
  - locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
  - export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
  - export LANGUAGE=en_US:en
  - export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```