# Liquid Exception: invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII in _layouts/redirect.html

Tags: jekyll, gitlab

I was using gitlab build of jekyll project, all of a sudden started receiving following error. Not able to solve after a lot of trials. What to do in .gitlab-ci.yml file to resolve this (*error not appearing in local machine, both .gitlab-ci.yml and locally uses "grunt build" command).

> Liquid Exception: invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII in _layouts/redirect.html

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36262382/jekyll-says-liquid-exception-invalid-byte-sequence-in-us-ascii-in-documentation?rq=1) solution did not worked. Tried deleting and recreating pages, force update bower, and npm packages - all failed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this very tricky issue by following:

- Disable & Re-enable GitLab CI Runner
- Deleted Gemfile.lock from the Runner (Commit)
- Deleted folders `node_modules` and `bower_components`
- Re-compiled project using last successful `.gitlab-ci.yml` and `GemFile`
- Replaced `.gitlab-ci.yml` and `GemFile` to latest versions

Comment: Am able to trace out root cause of this issue. Somehow, Gemfile.lock got committed to GitHub that had created all this trobule.

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/14983#note_4637913) solution worked for me.

Put:

```
before_script:
  - apt-get update >/dev/null
  - apt-get install -y locales >/dev/null
  - echo "en_US UTF-8" > /etc/locale.gen
  - locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
  - export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
  - export LANGUAGE=en_US:en
  - export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

In `before_script` directive in your `.gitlab-ci.yml`.